# Objective C - Box2d float type casting: multiplying * operand on float32

Tags: objective-c, casting, type-conversion, box2d-iphone

Please help me in removing the error with explanation

Error on the following line:

_Sprite.position.x = _Body->GetPosition().x * _PhysicsWorld->RATIO;

Error message: Invalid operands to binary expression ('float32 (aka 'float') and 'float32(*)()*)

_Body is a B2Body object

_Sprite is a CCSprite object

_PhysicsWorld->RATIO returns float32

If I change the line to:

_Sprite.position.x = _Body->GetPosition().x * (float) _PhysicsWorld->RATIO;

Another error message comes: C-style cast from float32(*)() to float is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to do:

```
_Sprite.position.x = _Body->GetPosition().x * _PhysicsWorld->RATIO();
```

Note the trailing '()' after RATIO.

You are multiplying a float (which parses into pointer dereferencing instead) by a function that returns a float (I believe).